# How to edit big file XML efficiently?

Tags: c#, xml

So basically I have a big XML file which have more than 300,000 lines. It looks like this:

```
<TextField>
    <ID>41445</ID>
    <Text>Passing over</Text>
</TextField>
<TextField>
    <ID>1123</ID>
    <Text>Press ESC to get back into the menu</Text>
</TextField>
```

I made a console program to read the file using `xmlDocument` and iterate each node to translate the text:

```
foreach (XmlNode item in nodeList)
{
    if (item.SelectSingleNode("Text") != null)
    {
         if (!re.IsMatch(item["Text"].InnerText)) //check if text is empty or number only
              item["Text"].InnerText = translate(item["Text"].InnerText, "en", "fr"); //trans from 1 to 2
    }
}
```

Basically the method to translate takes 0.5-1s to be done, so with the files that have so many lines, in my case it's over 300,000 which probably take me ages to finish translating that file. Do you have any better way to do it faster? I am thinking of splitting the nodes into small parts and let each thread do the job separately. But I really don't know how to do such thing. Thank you.

Comment: Why is the translation taking so long?

Comment: @CodeCaster Well I am using Yandex translate api to do the translate job and it takes me that amount of time to return the translated text. Probably just a delay due to being far away from their server.

Comment: you can split your xml file and translate those using Task, I think it will be first...

Comment: As I can understand, you requesting Translation API on each loop iteration. Thats mean many request-responses should be done. How about to take each `InnerText` value to List of strings, then request Translation API to translate all that strings as one text (hello `string.Join`). Then on response just split translated text into separated strings and set back to nodes?

Answer (score -1):

Using XML Linq is very fast.  Try following :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication4
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);

            Dictionary<string, string> dict = doc.Descendants("TextField")
                .GroupBy(x => (string)x.Element("ID"), y => (string)y.Element("Text"))
                .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.FirstOrDefault());
        }
    }
}
```